# Forcing download of txt file via PHP is including HTML

Tags: php

Basically, the user will be exporting some data to a txt file. That txt file will then download automatically. The download is working fine and is showing the data I want it to. However, the HTML of the actual page is getting appended onto the end of it?

```
$fh = fopen($filename, 'w');
fwrite($fh, $data); 
fclose($fh);

header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename='.$filename);
header('Content-type:  text/plain');
readfile($filename);
```

Comment: What actual page? Are you trying to provide two files (a download and an HTML document) in a single HTTP response? You can't do that, HTTP doesn't work like that.

Comment: Thanks! That's obviously the issue then. It's just that I've noticed other pages "acting" as if they're providing a page and a download at the same time.

Comment: If you've got a download script that also outputs HTML then you need to separate them.  The download script should output nothing except the data to be downloaded, or an error message if the download couldn't commence.

Comment: It appears as if the problem was caused by my failure to include exit; after readfile()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there is html after the code above, you may want to `exit` after `readfile($filename)`?

Comment: Thanks. I added exit after readfile() and it worked perfectly. I was under the impression that exit would kill the page completely.

Comment: It does kill the page, but it does so "nicely", letting any automatic cleanup functions and object destructors run first... but the problem is as stated in the comments, you can't serve a download file and an HTML page at the same time, and whenever you've seen something that looks like that, it's just pretending.  Usually it will download an HTML page, then once the page is loaded it will trigger the download, which doesn't actually change the page you're on if served correctly.